# How to access Ubuntu local web server from a different apartment

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, firewall

I have set up an Ubuntu Apache web server with a four years old laptop. And my web application needs to be used from a different apartment, from my ground floor shop. Actually, I'm an intermediate web programmer. I have a few questions about servers and networking as This is my first experience.

So how do I connect my Wi-Fi to my shop?

Could it use the same Wi-Fi name?

How can I deny internet access from my shop?

Comment: What is the IP of your laptop? Is it always the smae or does it vary? If it varies, you you use a DNS solution like DynDNS? Is the web server configured to bind on ::1 or 127.1 only, or also on the external interfaces?

Comment: Hi Ryan. I'm afraid your question isn't entirely clear. You want to connect your apartment's WiFi to the ground floor shop? What do you mean by "deny internet access from my shop" exactly? Who should be denied to access the Internet? Customers that connect to the WiFi?

Comment: Hi Hennes, Thanks for your reply.
My web server IP is 192.168.20.25, static IP. 
my web app can access with `http://myproject.dev.192.168.20.25.xip.io`.
I tested with different laptop within same wifi network.

Comment: Hi slhck, Actually, I don't want to allow my cashier to use internet in working hour. Mostly he always want to play facebook game. So I don't want to allow it.

Comment: Is the user on the ground floor connected to the same LAN as your server? Is the users computer also managed by you?

Comment: I'm planning to extend my network with WAP router in ground floor. I will not manage user computer. User will just use my web app. 
And This extended router isn't be allowed to access internet within my network.